# Which protocol should i use to back up my debian server remotely with netgear readynas?

Tags: backup

i have one debian server with a bunch of systems and information very valuable for daily operations, and i have a Netgear readynas back up disks solution, the netgear comes with a software that let you schedule jobs, what i need is a way to schedule back ups that enables me should an emergency happens, be online with a different hardware as soon as posible.

So, netgear gives me a bunch of options for making a job, of which only the first i understand, the others i don´t, would you please help me make sense of the other options and direct me on the right solution according to my needs ? is there a way to make a disk image and store it as a back up or something like it ?

Remote: FTP Server
Remote: NFS Server
Remote: Rsync server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly want rsync, for the most efficient way of backing up the system, it only sends over file differences.  Unfortunately thats not going to get you a bare-metal restore point.

There is other imaging software that will image your system for you, but generally the system can't be active for this to work.  (LVM Mirroring excepted)

If you just use the standard rsync mechanism, and wish to rebuild, you should be able to boot off of a live-cd disk, rsync over to the new media, chroot and do a grub-install for the boot manager and basically be ready to go.